# Hibernate:Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

this error gives me when i try to insert (save) an user using hibernate:

```
//SQL
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bytecodete`.`account_confirmation`;
CREATE TABLE  `bytecodete`.`account_confirmation` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FK_account_confirmation_1` (`email`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_account_confirmation_1` FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `user` (`email`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;



// HIBERNATE
@Entity
@Table(name = "account_confirmation", catalog = "bytecodete")
public class AccountConfirmation implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private User user;

    public AccountConfirmation() {
    }

    public AccountConfirmation(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "email", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

I first insert the object 'user' in the database then i try to insert this user in this table 'account_confirmation', but isn't possible.. i really don't understand why this happens.

Any idea ?

EDIT:
// LOG4J

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        bytecodete.user
        (email, password, type) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        bytecodete.person
        (birthDate, cpf, gender, idFacebook, name, tokenFacebook, idUser) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        bytecodete.account_confirmation
        (email) 
    values
        (?)
18:45:40,745  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:77 - SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000
18:45:40,746 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:78 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bytecodete`.`account_confirmation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_account_confirmation_1` FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `user` (`email`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Comment: Shouldn't you somehow have to tell hibernate that the user is the foreign key?  Perhaps in this case a one-to-one relationship?  I'm not positive how to do that using annotations.  Sorry.

Comment: @hooknc , it doesn't work i try what you suggest but keeps returning:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bytecodete`.`account_confirmation`, CONSTRAINT `FK_account_confirmation_1` FOREIGN KEY (`email`) REFERENCES `user` (`email`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: You should be able to turn on hibernate logging to see exactly what SQL is being executed.  For log4j you would use "org.hibernate.SQL" on DEBUG.  You might also consider using "org.hibernate" on DEBUG as well.  There has got to be something iffy with that mapping of your user object.  Do you have a mapping for that user object and are you able to add a user to your database?

Comment: @hooknc, i update my post and insert my LOG4J that hibernate do about the inserts.
Everything is fine before it try to insert the user object in the table account_confirmation, the user is inserted in the table user then i insert this same user to the table person, than i try to insert this user in the table account_confirmation.. but.. not happens.

Comment: can you also add the logging for the values going in?  I believe you would get that from the "org.hibernate" logging on debug or trace.  Perhaps there is a case difference between the email address'?

Comment: @hooknc, how could i change my log4j to see the values from my queries ?
this is my actual log4j: http://pastebin.com/uGpj3P75

Answer (score 0):

Are you saving the user and account confirmation in the same session? Is this a bidirectional relation or just unidirectional? (Maybe you should also post the content of the class user)